# Trouble with SplitContainer

Tags: c#, winforms, splitcontainer

Perhaps I do not understand how it works...

So there is a SplitContainer called 'newDevicesSpliContainer', which has got Panel1 and Panel2.

I'm trying to set Panel2 visible, it does not work. I tried setting property Panel2Collapsed to false, but it did not affect Visible property of Panel2. 
Of course, cannot manipulate value of Visible property directly...

What should be done in order to make Panel2 visible?

Comment: It is visible by default unless you set Panel2Collapsed = true. It doesn't work for you?

Comment: by default both panel are visible. Maybe could you explain a bit more what you are trying to do? Edit : btw are you using windowsform?

Comment: You are making your readers guess at the issue.  Examine the sizes of the sub panels and the SplitterDistance value.

Comment: @LarsTech SplitterDistance got value there, tried changing, but did not help. Checked the sizes, they look correct.

Comment: Try placing another SplitContainer on the form, which by default shows both Panels 1 & 2, and compare the differences in the PropertyGrid with your newDevicesSplitContainer control.